# Execute code if page doesn't load

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, connection, reload

I want to create a code that reloads a part of the page every 10 seconds and if it fails to reload (because of connection issue), then it plays a sound.

Is such thing possible using ajax and how? I have seen this type of feature in web chats before but never came across a code for it.

Comment: Are you asking about an ajax request failing, or if the actual page fails to load?

Comment: No not the initial page, but the ajax request failing. It is however important that the ajax function fails if there is a connection problem.

Comment: Are you using any Javascript frameworks like jQuery, or are you doing this with `XmlHttpRequest`?

Comment: Yes I am using latest version of jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using setInterval function:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
        <!--
          .square {
              background-color: #AAAAAA;
              width: 250px;
              height: 100px;
          }
        //-->
        </style>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
  $(document).on('ready',function(){
    setInterval(updateDiv,10000);
  });

  function updateDiv(){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'getContent.php',
      success: function(data){
        $('.square').html(data);
      },
      error: function(){
        //Code to play a sound
        $('.square').html('<span style="color:red">Connection problems</span>');
      }
    });
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>The next div will be updated every 10 seconds</h1>
  <div class="square">
    Hello
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the php script:

```
<?php
  echo "Updated value --> " . rand();
?>
```

To test, try renaming the php script (simulating connection problems) and rename to original name (getContent.php) to test correct situation again. Hope this helps.

Comment: Great answer, I will test this in a moment, just one final request. Can you advice me of a simple code to play a short WAV file? Maybe you can update your answer with this code?

Comment: @GaryWoods I've found ogg format to be the best for cross browser support for webpage sounds. If you don't need cross browser support you may be fine with wav, but ogg is the html5 standard I believe.

Comment: Gary, playing a sound is another great challenge!! that deserves another question to the forum. Try this (is the most complete from my viewpoint): [Sound Manager](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/)

Answer (score 1):

Using JQuery, you can add handlers to run on fail...

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "myurl.com"
}).done(function( data ) {
    //do what you want when it's all good
}).fail(function() {
    //do what you want when the call fails
});
```

Or you can do it this way...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post", 
    url: "/SomeController/SomeAction",
    success: function (data, text) {
        //do what you want when it's all good
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
         //do what you want when the call fails
    }
});
```

And per request, here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JvNe5/), it calls a service every 2 seconds, either with a URL that will return the date, or with a bad URL that will fail, mimicking a failed server.

UPDATE: I modified the jsfiddle to play a sound, as long as that sound remains on the server it's on :)

Comment: Can you please add a jsfiddle.net to your answer demonstrating this? Ideally one where it refreshes every 10 seconds and plays a sound if refresh fails.